# Searching for tags fetches the answers as well as the question

Tags: bug, search, ios-app

As can be seen, the same question showed 3 times with different 3 answers in the cell details.

I hope that it shouldn't be the case and it's only a bug

[image]

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Did you try this on the mobile or the full site to see if it is divergent behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a bug exactly, but the wording is confusing here. What you have here is actually the site's search functionality, which searches for both questions and answers. You can filter on either of them by providing `is:q` or `is:a`.

As noted by Shadow Wizard, the site redirects to the tag page if you search for one of the top tags, which isn't the case for the app. The 'bug' here is that you are in the question tab, so you expect to search on questions, but you aren't.

I think this can be fixed by just changing the wording or implementing the special redirect to the tag page. If the renaming is the way to go, maybe instead of showing *Questions* as page name, it could be *Posts* or *Search*. That would take away at least some of the confusion.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. As you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift?sort=active&pageSize=50), the site's search returns only questions when you type only tag(s). (So the app is expected to be consistent)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You might be wrong. It shows all active posts viz both questions and answers. Check your link again.

Comment: @Sha the difference is that the page you linked to isn't a search it's the tag page (the confusion comes from the fact that a search with a single tag redirects to the tag page instead of an actual search result on the site)

Comment: @Sha as Cai says. That special redirect to the tag page isn't implemented in the app, so that is the 'bug' leading to the confusion. Updated my answer.

Comment: True, guess now it's as correct as it can be. /cc @Cai

Answer (score 0):

It s not a bug. You selected to view "Newest posts" with selected tag. It showed three answers to the same question in the search results because they are the newest posts tagged under [swift](/questions/tagged/swift).

When you select "newest", it only shows the newest posts let them be question or answers. There are different options which you can select. You selected Newest posts with selected tag. Select

- "active" to view questions with recent activity.
- "featured" to view questions with active bounties.
- "votes" to view questions or answers with higher upvotes (in decreasing order).
- "unanswered" to view questions with no answers
- "frequent" to view popular questions with highest views.

[image: screenshot from mobile version]

Comment: You don't get the same options on the app and all the options return questions and answers so this is wrong

Comment: @Cai You say the screenshot is wrong or the answer totally? The OP selected only newest(see his screenshot). When we select "newest" it  shows newest posts. Options might be  different. You are welcome to edit with the screenshot from ios app.

Comment: It's not wrong per-se, it just doesn't apply to the app. The question is about the app, your answer explains how it works on the site. The options are totally different in the app and *all* the options available in the app show questions and answers